# Calculating MAPE in H2o: Error: Provided column type POSIXct is unknown

Tags: python, r, loops, prediction, h2o

Following my answered question: [R or Python - loop the test data - Prediction validation next 24 hours (96 values each day)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804842/r-or-python-loop-the-test-data-prediction-validation-next-24-hours-96-value)

I want to predict the next day using H2o Package. **You can find detail explanation for my dataset in the same above link**.

The data dimension in H2o is different.

So, after making the prediction, I want to calculate the MAPE

I have to change training and testing data to H2o format

```
train_h2o <- as.h2o(train_data)

test_h2o <- as.h2o(test_data)

mape_calc <- function(sub_df) {
  pred <- predict.glm(glm_model, sub_df)
  actual <- sub_df$Ptot
  mape <- 100 * mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))

  new_df <- data.frame(date = sub_df$date[[1]], mape = mape)

  return(new_df)
}

# LIST OF ONE-ROW DATAFRAMES
df_list <- by(test_data, test_data$date, map_calc)

# FINAL DATAFRAME
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

The upper code works well for "**Non-H2o**" prediction validation for the day-ahead and it calculates the MAPE for every day.

I tried to convert the H2o predicted model to normal format but according to to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39221269/9341589, it is not possible.

To make a prediction in H2O:

for instance, let say we want to create a Random Forest Model

```
y <- "RealPtot" #target
x <- names(train_h2o) %>% setdiff(y) #features


rforest.model <- h2o.randomForest(y=y, x=x, training_frame = train_h2o, ntrees = 2000, mtries = 3, max_depth = 4, seed = 1122)
```

Then we can get the prediction for complete dataset as shown below.

```
predict.rforest <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(rforest.model, test_h2o)
```

But in my case I am trying to get one-day prediction using mape_calc

---

**NOTE:** Any thoughts in R or Python will be appreciated.

**UPDATE2(reproducible example**):** Following @Darren Cook steps:

I provided a simpler example - Boston housing dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(h2o)
h2o.init(ip="localhost",port=54322,max_mem_size = "128g")


data(Boston, package = "MASS")

names(Boston)
[1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas"    "nox"     "rm"      "age"     "dis"     "rad"     "tax"     "ptratio"
[12] "black"   "lstat"   "medv"   


set.seed(4984)
#Added 15 minute Time and date interval 
Boston$date<- seq(as.POSIXct("01-09-2017 03:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",tz=""), by = "15 min", length = 506)

#select first 333 values to be trained and the rest to be test data
train = Boston[1:333,]
test = Boston[334:506,]

#Dropped the date and time
train_data_finialized  <- subset(train, select=-c(date))

test_data_finialized <- test

#Converted the dataset to h2o object.
train_h2o<- as.h2o(train_data_finialized)
#test_h2o<- as.h2o(test)

#Select the target and feature variables for h2o model
y <- "medv" #target
x <- names(train_data_finialized) %>% setdiff(y) #feature variables

# Number of CV folds (to generate level-one data for stacking)
nfolds <- 5

#Replaced RF model by GBM because GBM run faster
# Train & Cross-validate a GBM
my_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = x,
                  y = y,
                          training_frame = train_h2o,
                          nfolds = nfolds,
                          fold_assignment = "Modulo",
                          keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                          seed = 1)

mape_calc <- function(sub_df) {
  p <- h2o.predict(my_gbm, as.h2o(sub_df))
  pred <- as.vector(p)
  actual <- sub_df$medv
  mape <- 100 * mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))
  new_df <- data.frame(date = sub_df$date[[1]], mape = mape)
  return(new_df)
}


# LIST OF ONE-ROW DATAFRAMES
df_list <- by(test_data_finialized, test_data_finialized$date, mape_calc)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

This is the error I am getting now:

> Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,
>   urlSuffix = page,  :
>
> ERROR MESSAGE:
>
> Provided column type POSIXct is unknown.  Cannot proceed with parse
>   due to invalid argument.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  No one can run this code w/o changing it since you didn't use a public dataset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

H2O is running in a separate process to R (whether H2O is on the local server or in a distant data centre). The H2O data and the H2O models are kept in that H2O process, and cannot be seen by R.

What `dH <- as.h2o(dR)` does is copy an R data frame, `dR`, into H2O's memory space. The `dH` is then an R variable that describes the H2O data frame. I.e. it is a pointer, or a handle; it is not the data itself.

What `dR <- as.data.frame(dH)` does is copy the data from the H2O process's memory, into the R process's memory.  (`as.vector(dH)` does the same for when dH describes a single column)

So, the simplest way to modify your `mape_calc()`, assuming that `sub_df` is an R data frame, is to change the first two lines as follows:

```
mape_calc <- function(sub_df) {
  p <- h2o.predict(rforest.model, as.h2o(sub_df))
  pred <- as.vector(p)

  actual <- sub_df$Ptot
  mape <- 100 * mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))

  new_df <- data.frame(date = sub_df$date[[1]], mape = mape)

  return(new_df)
}
```

I.e. upload `sub_df` to H2O, and give that to `h2o.predict()`. Then use `as.vector()` to download the prediction that was made.

This was relative to your original code. So keep the original version of this:

```
# LIST OF ONE-ROW DATAFRAMES
df_list <- by(test_data, test_data$date, map_calc)
```

I.e. don't use `by()` directly on `test_h2o`.

---

**UPDATE** based on edited question:

I made two changes to your example code. First, I removed the date column from `sub_df`. That was what was causing the error message.

The second change was just to simplify the return type; not important, but you ended up with the date column duplicated, before.

```
mape_calc <- function(sub_df) {
  sub_df_minus_date <- subset(sub_df, select=-c(date))
  p <- h2o.predict(my_gbm, as.h2o(sub_df_minus_date))
  pred <- as.vector(p)
  actual <- sub_df$medv
  mape <- 100 * mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))
  data.frame(mape = mape)
}
```

---

**ASIDE:** `h2o.predict()` is most efficient when working on a batch of data to make predictions on. Putting `h2o.predict()` inside a loop is a code smell. You would be better to call `h2o.predict(rforest.model, test_h2o)` once, outside the loop, then download the predictions into R, and `cbind` them to test_data, and then use `by` on that combined data.

**UPDATE** Here is your example changed to work that way: (I've added the prediction as an extra column to the test data; there are other ways to do it, of course)

```
 test_h2o <- as.h2o(subset(test_data_finialized, select=-c(date)))
 p <- h2o.predict(my_gbm, test_h2o)
 test_data_finialized$pred = as.vector(p)

 mape_calc2 <- function(sub_df) {
   actual <- sub_df$medv
   mape <- 100 * mean(abs((actual - sub_df$pred)/actual))
   data.frame(mape = mape)
 }

 df_list <- by(test_data_finialized, test_data_finialized$date, mape_calc2)
```

You should notice that it runs much quicker.

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE**: `by()` works by grouping same values of your 2nd argument, and processing them together. As all your timestamps are different, you are processing one row at a time.

Look into the `xts` library, and e.g. `apply.daily()` to group timestamps. But for the simple case of wanting to process by date, there is a simple hack. Change your `by()` line to:

```
df_list <- by(test_data_finialized, as.Date(test_data_finialized$date), mape_calc2)
```

Using `as.Date()` will strip off the times. Therefore all the rows on the same day now look the same and get processed together.

**ASIDE 2:** You would get better responses if your make the infamous [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then people can run your code, and they can test their answers. It is also often better to use a simple data set everyone has, e.g. iris, rather than your own data. (You can do regression on any of the first 4 fields; using iris does not have to always be about predicting the species.)

**ASIDE 3**: You can do MAPE completely inside H2O, as the `abs()` and `mean()` functions will work directly on H2O data frames (as do lots of other things - see the H2O manual): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103229/841830
(I'm not marking this as a duplicate, as your question was how to adapt `by()` for use with H2O data frames, not how to calculate MAPE efficiently!)

Comment: Dear @Darren Cook I still have an issue in the prediction: this is the dimension of train_h2o [66816 rows x 19 columns] and the dimension of test_h2o [18524 rows x 19 columns]. I am using "test_data_finialized" which is the 'data.frame' set. and has same dimention as test_data_finialized. I am getting: Error in names(IND) <- deparse(substitute(INDICES))[1L]: 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Traceback: .... I will update my post.

Comment: It will be great if you can make the answer by showing the result with a reproducible example. Again, Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @KingJulien If you can modify your question to have a fully reproducible example, I could edit it/test against it.  (Remember a reproducible example is likely to start with `library(h2o)`, define all data, etc. I.e. allow me to copy and paste into an R session and run it, and see the same error message you get, without having to do anything else.)

Comment: I provided Boston data to be reproducible and much simpler than my dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I meant 96 rows.

Comment: I am getting very big MAPE numbers for insurance 138

Comment: I am also getting some reasonable ones I.e 1.3 MAPE

Comment: @KingJulien I've been answering the "how do I port this code, using `by`, to work with H2O" question, which I think is your question here. You might want to open a new question for each other question you have (assuming it fits the StackOverflow Q&A concept)  (Regarding 96 columns: I've not touched the way you are using `by`, and I don't know your data; with the Boston test data it is obviously doing one row at a time, as your timestamps are all different.)

Comment: Actually, this was my main question as it is stated clearly in the title.- how to predict day-ahead using h2o.Thank you so much.

Comment: I will never forget your favor if you can show me how to (predict day ahead) using any dataset or any steps at your convenience. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @KingJulien I suggest you edit the title to match the body of the question, and start a new question for the next thing you want to know. (BTW, "how to (predict day ahead) using any dataset" would probably get closed as too broad. It has to be a specific, clearly defined question to fit in well, here.)

Comment: Dear @Dareen Cook here is my new question. I hope it is clear : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138212/how-to-predict-day-ahead-using-h20 please feel free to edit anything. I just want to take each time 96 values -15 minute sampling- and make prediction for it.

Comment: @KingJulien See my additional update on how `by` works.

Comment: @Dear Dareen Cook, If you can add additional step show the complete code with no errors as final update it will be so great. I am having difficulties in following up the instructions because when we take out the date and in the ADDITIONAL UPDATE we are requesting the date it will not work because we will have an additional variable. For the last update please add the final update including all of the code. It will be truly a huge favor for me, Thanks.

Comment: @KingJulien This is a Q&A site, not a write-your-code-for-you site ;-) I'd suggest ask a new specific question if there is one, or consider hiring a developer or consultant to help you.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are mixing up R and H2O data types. Remember H2O's R is simply an R API and is not the same as native R. This means that you can't apply an R function that expects an R dataframe to an H2OFrame. And likewise you can't apply an H2O Function to an R dataframe when it expects an H2OFrame.

As you can see from the R docs on `by` it's a function that expects "an R object, normally a data frame, possibly a matrix" so you can't pass in an H2O frame.

Similarly you are passing `date = H2OFrame` to `data.frame()`.

However you can use the `as.data.frame()` to convert an H2OFrame to an R dataframe and then go about your calculations entirely in R.

Comment: If your prediction frame isn't too big, I'd suggest just converting your H2O predictions frame to an R frame and continuing using the R functions you used before.

Answer (score 0):

Could it simply be the file format that is the problem?  I got "Provided column type POSIXct is unknown" after I imported from Excel and ran:

```
hr_data_h2o <- as.h2o(hr_data)
split_h2o <- h2o.splitFrame(hr_data_h2o, c(0.7, 0.15), seed = 1234)
```

I changed the source file to tab delimited (no other changes) and the problem went away.